# How to define multiple media queries in one stylus file?

Tags: stylus

How do I define multiple media queries in one file?

I have this .styl-file:

```
@media (min-width: 980px)
  body
    padding-top 60px

@media (min-width: 768px)
  body
    .container
      width 768px
```

This is giving me the error `expected "indent", got "newline"`. Placing them in separate files and having one file include the other works. But when I have them in the same file and a second file that is importing this one it fails.

**Update:** The code of the files can be found here:

- https://github.com/mastoj/NodeJsExpressFun/blob/master/public/stylesheets/style.styl
- https://github.com/mastoj/NodeJsExpressFun/blob/master/public/stylesheets/nblog.styl

Comment: Which version of Stylus? It works for me with 0.24.0.

Comment: @LinusGThiel, I think I have version 0.24.0 as well. Is there an easy check to check the version? As I did it know I browsed down to the stylus.js file and checked the exported version.

Comment: I figured it out, it is the command `npm ls`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you have tabs in the top query, and spaces in the lower. Try to be consistent (this is a good practice in general, when it comes to all kinds of programming). I don't have a preference either way, but you should probably look into your editor settings to see if you can enforce consistency on that level. My editor puts 4 or 2 spaces when I press tab, depending on language.

Your example in the question works, actually (there's only spaces in that one).

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'll try it later on and I'll try to configure my cloud 9 editor correct.

Comment: Cool. This is also why it worked when the queries were in separate files -- stylus is sensitive to mixed tabs and spaces, but it can  handle both fine on their own (similar to most languages with significant whitespace).